# Узнать какой из дочерних радио элементов выбран js

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени! есть у меня форма такая

```
 <form>

 <table><tr><td>1</td><td><input type='radio' name='ityp' value='1'></td></tr></table>
 <table><tr><td>2</td><td><input type='radio' name='ityp' value='2'></td></tr></table>
 <table><tr><td>3</td><td><input type='radio' name='ityp' value='3'></td></tr></table>
 <input type='button' class='checker'>
 </form>
```

мне нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку в переменную записывалось значение радио которое было нажато

пробовал через перебор в цикле делать примерно так

```
$(document).on("click", ".checker", function () {

    $(this).parent('form').children('table').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td:last-child').children("input[type='redio']").each(function(i, e){ 
//ну и тут собственно проверка нажат или нет может гдето ошибся в написани но это только для примера показываю
    });
});
```

суть в том что это слишком громоздко выглядит, можно ли как то по проще реализовать данную конструкцию?

Comment: Какая жуть...воспользоваться всплытием

Comment: Дааа... Что-то вы замарочились...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
console.log($(this).closest('form').find("input[type='radio']:checked").val());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var value = document.querySelector('input[name="ityp"]:checked').value;
```